# The argument type can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'

Tags: python, flutter

I have a Flask python backend that returns an image in form of a list, I'd like to get this image data to my Flutter app and then convert it to a file, but I get this error

> The argument type 'Response' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'List'

Return image is in this format

```
[67, 53, 81], [69, 55, 83], [72, 59, 85], [68, 55, 79], [62, 50, 72], [52, 39, 61], [44, 32, 52], [44, 30, 48], [47, 34, 50], [41, 24, 38], [47, 30, 43], [46, 29, 40], [32, 13, 22], [42, 23, 32], [59, 38, 47], [52, 31, 40], [54, 30, 40], [57, 33, 43], [74, 50, 60], [76, 53, 61], [66, 46, 51], [68, 47, 50], [72, 51, 54], [57, 36, 38], [57, 37, 36], [61, 41, 40], [62, 43, 40], [71, 52, 49], [77, 58, 55], [81, 62, 59], [78, 59, 56],.....
```

Flutter code:

```
Future pix(String BackgroundImagePath, String originalImagePath) async {
  final uri = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000').replace( queryParameters : {
  'original': originalImagePath,
  'background': BackgroundImagePath,
  });

  final response = await http.get(uri);

  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  File file = await File('${tempDir.path}/image.png').create();
  file.writeAsBytesSync(response); //error here
  return file;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `response.data` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the variable `response` is an object of `Response` class from http package. So if your response body is `List<int>` then you will have to pass `response.body`. And if it is String, you will have to convert it to Unit8List.

Comment: it is supposed to be a list as shown in my post , but if I used `response.body` , it gives me (The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>' ), I tried to convert to Unit8List using `Uint8List.fromList` , but it gives same error!

Comment: Yes. response.body will always give you string. So you have to convert string to list so it would be `response.body.codeUnits`

Comment: I see , so after that i should pass it to `Uint8List.fromList` to convert to Unit8List . Right?

Comment: No. You won't need to convert it to Unit8List. You can directly write `file.writeAsBytesSync(response.body.codeUnits);`